# Modelview and viewpager2: how can I stop to observe the liveData when the page is not visible?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-livedata, android-viewmodel, android-viewpager2

This is my issue recipe:

- a fragment container
- a fragment container viewmodel
- viewPager 2
- N fragments and for each fragment I have a modelView
- repository shared between the modelView

Inside the repository I have a LiveData and in each modelview I use the trasformations.map method to observe it and trasform it in a liveData observed by the inner fragment.

My problem happens when I swipe the page, because the fragment not visible continues to observe the repo live data and the relative fragment continues to be triggered.

The following is the inner fragment onActivityCreated:

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

    ......

    viewModel.getRowItems().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        baseTableAdapter.refreshList(it)
    })
    .....
```

This is the innerFragment's viewModel getRowItems() method:

```
fun getRowItems(): LiveData<Array<out RowItem>> {
    return Transformations.map( repository.getRowListLiveData()
    ) {
        ....
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Observe in `onResume`, remove observer in `onPause`.

Comment: Do you suggest me to move this  
viewModel.getRowItems().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        baseTableAdapter.refreshList(it)
    })
 into onResume and inside onPause call the getRowItems().removeObserver ?

Call Trasformations.map every time could bring me problem because I attach every time a new observer ?

Comment: Exactly. It shouldn't be a problem, but you can cache the transformation, for example by declaring `val rowItems by lazy { ... }` instead of having a function.

Comment: I will try ! Thank you :)

Comment: I have tryed, but now I have one problem.. When I swich the page there is a delay before appears data.
Because now I start to observe data only in onResume method :(

Comment: have you found the solution of this problem?